# cannot as mutable more than once at a time error when chaning values in a map

Tags: rust

The following code works properly:

```rust
let mut results = HashMap::new();

let a = results.entry("a".to_string()).or_insert("1".to_string());
*a = "11".to_string();
let b = results.entry("b".to_string()).or_insert("2".to_string());
*b = "22".to_string();
```

However, if changes the code order to:

```rust
let mut results = HashMap::new();

let a = results.entry("a".to_string()).or_insert("1".to_string());
let b = results.entry("b".to_string()).or_insert("2".to_string());
*a = "11".to_string();
*b = "22".to_string();
```

there occurs a compile error said:

```
cannot borrow `results` as mutable more than once at a time

let a = results.entry("a".to_string()).or_insert("1".to_string());
        ------------------------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
let b = results.entry("b".to_string()).or_insert("2".to_string());
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
*a = "11".to_string();
-- first borrow later used here
```

In my view, I just borrowd `a` and `b` which are totally different variables. May I know what the real differences between the two code segments are please?

Comment: Because of the way methods work the borrow on `resutls` is kept for as long as anything returned from `.entry` is in scope. First case only works because Rust drops `a` early.

Comment: That is what just confuses me. I borrowed two different entries from a map but the map itself, didn't it? Or, should any modifications to an entries of a map be considered as the modications to the map itself?

Comment: Yes, the compiler only considers the signature for borrow checking and thus doesn't know `entry("a")` and `entry("b")` are not overlapping. Even if you only need part of it the whole `results` is borrowed.